# Custom map reduce functions in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

i want to use Couchbase Map Reduce Functionality.
My input is as follows:

```html
{
  "domain": "cnn.com",
  "country": "USA",
  "value": 1
}
```

Each document represent a single access to a domain from a specific source country,
I want to be able to query the count of accesses for a domain and country
meaning i want to group by (domain,country) and sum (value)
how can i write the reduce function that does that?

wanted output :

```html
{
  "domain": "cnn.com",
  "country": "USA",
  "value": 5
}
....
{
  "domain": "cnn.com",
  "country": "France",
  "value": 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have 4 documents like this:

```
{"domain":"cnn.com","country":"USA","value":5}
{"domain":"cnn.com","country":"USA","value":6
{"domain":"cnn.com","country":"France","value":2}
{"domain":"cnn.com","country":"France","value":10}
```

then the map would be:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit([doc.domain, doc.country], doc.value);
}
```

and the reduce is a simple as `_sum`. In your query remember to set enabled the `group` in order to have the summing to work.

The result would look like below image:
[image]